# JQuery how to remove tr in table which are display none in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to remove `tr` in a `table` which is `display:none` in CSS

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its related Jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all `tr` which is having `style="display: none;"` by following `jQuery` code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery( "tr" ).each(function( index ) {
        if (jQuery( this ).css('display') == 'none'){
            jQuery(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

**Description:** Above code will check for `style="display: none;` for each tr element, if found it will remove.
If you want to remove tr for specific table, You can use table class in code hierarchy

A working demo at [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pawankparmar/z34txnho/)

Hope above will help!